# Using strtok to replace parts of a string from input file C

Tags: c, string, strtok

So I have a file that is simply "cat dog chicken rat". I'm trying to load it into a string and change one of the words. I have

```
int main(){

    FILE *ifp;
    char *entry;
    char *string;
    char *token;

    ifp=fopen("/home/names.txt", "r");

    entry=malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    while(fgets(entry,75,ifp)){ 
    }

    printf("%s\n",entry);
    token=strtok(entry," ");

    while(token!=NULL){

        if(token=="dog")
            string="bird";

        string=token;
        printf("%s ",string);
        token=strtok(NULL," "); 
    }   
}
```

However when I try this, it does not replace the word "dog" with "bird". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to replace it in the file?

Comment: No, just in the string I'm loading it into

Comment: 1) `while(fgets(entry,75,ifp)){ 
    }` 2)  `token=="dog"` 3) `string=token;` 4) omitted

Comment: `while(fgets(entry,75,ifp)){ 
    }` gets only the last line of the file. And why 75 and not 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will now modify original string and store it in a different char array -

```
char string[100];                // in your original code allocate memory to pointer string
token=strtok(entry," ");
size_t n;
while(token!=NULL){
  n=strlen(string);                      // calculate string length 
  if(strcmp(token,"dog")==0)             // if "dog" found
     sprintf(&string[n],"bird ");        // add "bird " at that position
  else
     sprintf(&string[n],"%s ",token);    //if doesn't add token 
  token=strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

**note** - Don't compare strings like this -

```
    if(token=="dog")
```

Use function `strcmp` from `<string.h>`.

Comment: So this helps me to print out the replaced word. But what if I want to store the whole thing into another string?

Comment: @sam I have updated the code. It will update the original string .Please take a look.